# Propositional logic and probabilities

Tags: probability, propositional-calculus

I have four propositions $A, B, C, D$ each of which is either true or false. These statements are completely arbitrary and have no relation to each other. Is it logically sound to make the statement, $P(A=T)=\frac{1}{2}$, that is, the probability of A being true is one half? - *I realised my initial question had this as a presupposition so I thought it best to check this too.*

My actual question is this:

Given the same $A, B, C, D$ and then add in these relations

$TWO(A, B, C)$ (two of A, B and C are true, one is false)

$A \rightarrow D$

$B \rightarrow D$

Can we conlude $P(D=T)=\frac{2}{3}$ or is there a technical reason why applying probabilities to logic is fallacious in some sense? *(I'm new to formal logic and appreciate I may have misused a technical term somewhere)*

Thanks in advance, Ben

Comment: In the first paragraph, you wrote $A,B,C, D$ 'have no relation to each other', while in the specific question, $A\to D$ and $B\to D$ are imposed.

Comment: These additional relations are 'later' established. I think the best way to explain this would be with sudoku. In the beginning, you may have a few empty cells that bear no relation to each other but as the puzzle evolves you may learn of some relations between cells. Maybe $A1=3 \rightarrow A2=4$, I began with some propositions that had no relation *and then added in these relations*. I hope that is reasonable.

Comment: Do you mean $A, B, C = 0.5,...$ find $P(D)$? If $A, B, C$, and $D$ are all *equally* likely then you either have your answer ($P(D)=P(A)5$ by definition) or a contradiction (e.g $\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{2}$).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the statements are, but most likely not.

You can only do this if you know that $A,B,C$ are all *equally likely to occur*. This is obviously a major point in probability -- all outcomes must be equally likely. A more subtle note is that they *are actually probabilistic*. This means they can't be statements whose truthiness or falseness is determined, for instance a statement asserting that the twin prime conjecture is true. Even though this is unproven, it's still either true or untrue; there's no chances involved.

Comment: I would have thought that the twin prime conjecture is currently at $P(T)=0.5$ I think that probabilities would only come into it when XOR generalisations come into play. I've just made another question asking about that term too.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253158/name-for-this-family-of-operations